# Deploy to AWS EC2 from AWS S3 via Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a requirement to do CI/CD using Bitbucket Pipelines.
We use Maven to build our code on Bitbucket pipelines and push the artifacts (jars) to AWS S3. The missing link is to figure out a way to get the artifacts from S3 and deploy to our EC2 instance.

It should all work from Bitbucket Pipelines yml - hopefully using Maven plugins.

For pushing the artifacts to S3 we use:

```
<groupId>com.gkatzioura.maven.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>s3-storage-wagon</artifactId>
```

Is there a way/plugin that will download the artifact from S3's bucket and deploy it to EC2 instance specific folder and perhaps call a `sh` script to run the jars?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use AWS Code Deploy (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html) to deploy it to the EC2 instance. The trigger for code deploy would be the S3 bucket that you deploy your jars to. You will need to turn S3 versioning on to make it work. Code Deploy has it's own set of hooks that you can use to perform any shell command or run any bat files on the EC2.

Comment: I was hoping for a maven plugin so I can do a full cycle just running `mvn deploy`.